# Проблемы с индексацией страницы

Tags: html, seo, google-search

я столкнулся с проблемой при индексации в поисковике Google. Есть страница https://frontext.ru/posts/2020-08-27-making-cross-browser-and-responsiveness-better, через несколько дней заметил, что она исключена из поисковика, стал разбираться и оказалось, что Lighthouse для смартфонов выдаёт такую ошибку в Accessibility:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём видно, что конкретные элементы не указаны. Пробежался по странице и ничего страшного в контрасте на заметил. Убирал элементы, заменял цвета, ничего не менялось.
Остаётся только хайлайтер кода, который выглядит так:

```
<pre class="hljs" style="display: block; overflow-x: auto; padding: 0.5em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: rgb(248, 248, 248);"><span class="hljs-keyword" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: 700;">if</span> (<span class="hljs-string" style="color: rgb(221, 17, 68);">"ontouchstart"</span> <span class="hljs-keyword" style="color: rgb(51, 51, 51); font-weight: 700;">in</span> <span class="hljs-built_in" style="color: rgb(0, 134, 179);">document</span>.documentElement) {
  <span class="hljs-comment" style="color: rgb(153, 153, 136); font-style: italic;">//if true</span>
}</pre>
```

Подскажите, что может быть такого криминального в нём, либо же проблема в другом? Другие страницы без проблем индексируются, там не вставлен этот хайлайтер. Сайт на Nuxt.js, если это имеет значение.

Answer (score 0):

Указанная вами веб-страница имеет изображения в формате svg. Поэтому может быть полезным использовать рекомендации для доступности этого формата от **[paciellogroup](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/12/using-aria-enhance-svg-accessibility/)**, которая есть одна из ведущих групп разработчиков доступности в вебе:

```html
<body>
...
<svg xmlns=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg role="img" aria-labelledby="title  desc">
   <title id="title">Circle</title>
   <desc id="desc">Large red circle with a black border</desc>
   <circle role="presentation" cy="60" r="55" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" 
   fill="red" />
</svg>
…
</body>
```

О доступности в веб вы можете смотреть ресурсы:

- [Accessible Rich Internet Applications (WAI-ARIA) 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/)
- [Основы WAI-ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/WAI-ARIA_basics)
- [Introduction to ARIA](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/semantics-aria)
- [Accessible to all](https://web.dev/accessible/)

Comment: На всех страницах присутствуют одни и те же svg, но из индекса выпала именно эта. Я привёл кусок кода из-за которого вероятно ломается Lighthouse, но я ума не приложу почему, там нет ничего необычного.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, как и предполагалось проблема была в хайлайтере кода, а именно необходим был тег code внутри тега pre. По какой-то непонятной причине, при установке ширины тега pre или всей статьи гуглбот выдавал ошибку в accessibility, при наличии обёртки code такой проблемы не возникало. Установлен дефолтный nuxt/markdownit хайлайтер, всё в порядке, страница в индексе. Может, кто ещё столкнётся с такой проблемой и найдет ответ.